# Moq and setting properties in a class

Tags: moq

I have a class with properties in it that are populated via a loader class.  Quick example:

```
class Employee : IEmployee
{
   public string EmpFirstName {get; set}
   public string EmpLastName {get; set}
}

public class EmpLoader(int employeeID)
{
   public void Load(IEmployee emp)
   {
     emp.EmpFirstName = //lookup the employee using the EmployeeID 
     //...
   }
}
```

I'm wondering how to go about arranging things so that a mocked `EmpLoader`'s `Load()` method fills in particular values in the `Employee`.  Something like:

```
Employee myEmp = new Employee();
_empLoader = new Mock<EmpLoader>();
_empLoader.Setup(empL => empL.Load(myEmp)).Sets_myEmp_Properties_Somehow();
```

I've used Moq's `Setup()` method before when deciding what sort of return values come back, but wasn't sure if I can use it or another method to set properties in one class via a third party class.  Could be I'm way off here; I'm not an expert in Moq and am open to suggestions.

Comment: So, basically you want to set the property for the mock Employee based on some input on Load?

Comment: @rae1n-- that's exactly right.  Mike's answer below looks very promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Callback() method on the Setup() to load the data:

```
Employee myEmp = new Employee();
Mock<EmpLoader> _empLoader = new Mock<EmpLoader>();
_empLoader.Setup(empL => empL.Load(myEmp)).Callback<IEmployee>((emp) => {
    emp.EmpFirstName = "Steve";
    // ... Load all properties
}
```